# C# listbox split to another 2 listboxes

Tags: c#

Problem:
I have 1 ListBox which loads a text file contain:

- ip:port
- ip:port
- ip:port

What I want to do is, once I've loaded the text file into the list box, I want to have the 'ip' to go into a different listbox and the 'port' into a different listbox. This is first time working on a project like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
        {
            String line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
               string[] ipandport = line.split(":");
               lstBoxIp.Items.Add( ipandport[0] );
               lstBoxPort.Items.Add( ipandport[1] );
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Split(..) method accepts a char as an argument BTW. String generates a compiler error :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// if you wanted to do it with LINQ. 
// of course you're loading all lines 
// into memory at once here of which 
// you'd have to do regardless
var text = File.ReadAllLines("TestFile.txt");
var ipsAndPorts = text.Select(l => l.Split(':')).ToList();

ipsAndPorts.ForEach(ipAndPort =>
{
    lstBoxIp.Items.Add(ipAndPort[0]);
    lstBoxPort.Items.Add(ipAndPort[1]);
});
```